# Different column's behavior in Infragistics.UltraGrid

Tags: contextmenu, infragistics, right-click, contextmenustrip, ultrawingrid

I have an Infragistics.UltraGrid and I want to add a right-click event on it. I have 6 columns in grid and when I click on last four columns of six I call context menu, but when I right click on first and second column nothing is happen.

By the way if I right click on first or second column and then right-click on other columns, my context menu disappear.

So can you please answer me what's wrong with first two columns?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in any way. Could you show the code you use to add the contextmenu and what you do when the contextmenu events fires?

Comment: Can you also provide what editor is being used for the columns or if it is the default editor, what the data type for the column is.